# Relatório Jasper só funciona na aplicação local, não funciona no Servidor Web

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, web-service, aplicação-web, jasper

Meu relatório de impressão só está funcionando na aplicação local, usando conexão com Hibernate, quando tento rodar no servidor não funciona por falta de conexão com o banco de dados, como posso usar uma conexão sem ser usando a do Hibernate e que funcione na Aplicação Web?

**RelatorioMB.java**

```
public void imprimirVenda() {
    Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<>();
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();
    RelatorioVenda executor = new RelatorioVenda("/impressao/imp_venda.jasper",
            response, parametros, "Impressão da Venda.pdf", this.vendaMB.getVenda().getIdvenda());
    Session session = manager.unwrap(Session.class);
    session.doWork(executor);
    facesContext.responseComplete();
}
```

**RelatorioVenda.java**

```
  public class RelatorioVenda implements Work {

private final String caminhoRelatorio;
private final HttpServletResponse response;
private final Map<String, Object> parametros;
private final String nomeArquivoSaida;
private final Long id;

public RelatorioVenda(String caminhoRelatorio,
        HttpServletResponse response, Map<String, Object> parametros,
        String nomeArquivoSaida, Long id) {
    this.caminhoRelatorio = caminhoRelatorio;
    this.response = response;
    this.parametros = parametros;
    this.nomeArquivoSaida = nomeArquivoSaida;
    this.id = id;
}

@Override
public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    try {
        String relatorioStream = servlet.getRealPath(this.caminhoRelatorio);

        parametros.put("idvenda", id );
        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(relatorioStream, this.parametros, connection);

        Exporter<ExporterInput, PdfReportConfiguration, PdfExporterConfiguration, OutputStreamExporterOutput> exportador = new JRPdfExporter();
        exportador.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(print));
        exportador.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(response.getOutputStream()));

        response.setContentType("application/pdf");

        exportador.exportReport();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new SQLException("Erro ao executar relatório ", e);
    }
}
```

}

Alguém me ajuda a fazer outra conexão com o Banco de Dados. Agradeço desde já

Comment: Amigo seu problema é de conexão com o banco o problema não esta no relatorio, precisa analizar suas classes que geram a conexão, poe a classe de conexão ai, tal como url que usa para conectar no banco

Comment: Esse é o problema que não to conseguindo resolver, to tentando fazer uma conexão, passando a url, usuário e senha, mas ta dando erro

Comment: Se voce nao adicionar a sua classe de conexao fica dificil de te ajudar. Ao meu ver voce esta carregando na aplicação do servidor a url do banco local na sua maquina e nao do banco no servidor, por isso queria ver a sua classe de conexao

Comment: Resolvi o problema com essa conexão do banco.  `public Connection getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            System.out.println("Conectando ao banco");
            return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/teste", "root", "123");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Não conectado");
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }` .

Comment: Afinal qual era o problema? Estou vendo q a URL ainda é de um PC local e não de um servidor

Comment: Mas serviu assim